# How can I generate URLs with random IDs for new users and make them valid

Tags: php, html, backend, web-development-server

I'm trying to develop a site which asks or a username and creates a dare for their friends through a unique URL with a random ID.

I succeeded in generating random IDs with PHP `uniqid()` function
to append them in URL.

But I have no idea to make the generated URLs valid.

All I need to make the generated URLs valid when they are opened and display a welcome page with the username.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Please refer to the [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section in order to create a complete and answerable question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can pass the ID in a query string of the URL, that would be easiest approach:

```
http://yoursite.com/?ID=1234
```

You can append query string (the part that starts with **?**) to any URL and it will still load just as fine. If you need to add more parameters, use **&**. For example: `?ID=1234&name=Username`.
These parameters are then accessible from global $_GET variable, or you can filter it out of the input stream:

```
$id = $_GET["ID"]; // This variable contains the ID passed in URL query string
$id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "ID"); // This will produce the same result
```